# Find all objects between player and camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using an orthographic projection for camera to follow a player. I would like to find all gameobjects between the player and the camera so I can change the opacity so they are partially transparent while blocking the camera's view. I read about raycasting, but it seems it would give only the first object between the player and camera. What approaches are there to accomplish this?

Comment: `RaycastAll` -> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastAll.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Physics.RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) like this:

```
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Attach this script to the camera//

    public GameObject player;

    void Update()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.Position, player.transform.position);
        RaycastHit[] hits = hits = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, 
                                                      transform.forward, 100.0F);
        foreach (RaycastHit h in hits)
        {
            //Change the opacity of the of each object to semitransparent.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a version of this working where I can turn off the renderer of the object. In my case, the prefabs I am using from the asset store do not like having the shaders render mode set to anything but opaque. So having objects disappear completely is a bit odd, so I will have to pursue a different approach. Thank you.

Comment: Ok i see. Well glad I could help.