# Show silhouette or outline of player through other gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using an orthographic camera view where the camera follows the player, but does not rotate. When the player goes behind other objects I need a way to still see it. I played with [hiding the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319795/find-all-objects-between-player-and-camera) but the prefabs I am using from the asset store do not seem to work well unless they are rendered opaque.

How can I have the player show through other objects, or have an outline or 'ghost' of the player visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use another camera which will have same behaviour (same position/rotation, movement) as your main camera but will only render the player's layer. so when player goes behind other objects, this camera can still see it and make sure it renders on top of everything else using `Depth` property of camera.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have added a 2nd camera, but I do not quite understand what settings to use. I left the original camera untouched. I added the player to a new layer and also assigned that new layer to the camera. I made the 2nd camera depth 0 and the original camera has depth -1, but the player is still hidden behind behind other objects.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You must also change the culling mask. Thanks.

Comment: This works, but the effect is a bit silly. Is there a way to have everything on the 2nd camera render to a lower alpha or partially transparent?